# How do I dynamically generate forms with JINJA

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

What is the best way to generate a full styled form using flask and jinja

```html
           <div class="form">
            {{ form.statement_reference.label() }}
            {{ form.statement_reference(value=username) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form">
            {{ form.date.label() }}
            {{ form.date() }}
            </div>
            <div class="form">
            {{ form.full_name.label() }}
            {{ form.full_name() }}
            </div>
            <div class="form">
            {{ form.address_line_1.label() }}
            {{ form.address_line_1() }}
            </div>
            <div class="form">
            {{ form.city.label() }}
            {{ form.city() }}
            </div>
```

If I pass them to the template in a list and then iterate over the list, how to I create the label() as well?

something like this;

```html
{% for item in my_list %}
     {{ form.{item}.label() }}
{% endfor %}
```

How would i create these but without having to explicitly stating each one?

Comment: if you use bootstrap you can do `{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}` after importing via `{% import 'bootstrap/wtf.html' as wtf %}` otherwise you'll want to write a macro

Comment: Thanks , ill give that a go now